# Async call to GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber frequently returns 'NULL' block (Nethereum)

Tags: nethereum, c#, async, .net

Calling `GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber` asynchronoulsy from within a ProcessorForContract frequently returns NULLs. If I execute the following:

```
HexBigInteger blockNumber = new HexBigInteger(sl.Log.BlockNumber);
blockFromChain = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(blockNumber);
```

I very often get a NULL value in `blockFromChain` but if I select "set next statement" from within the VS debugger and selects the async call again it will indeed return a block. To me it seems that the async call doesn't wait 'til the actual block has been returned. The reason I make a GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber from within my (Create)ProcessorForContract async method is that I need to get the actual block timestamp as my TransferEventDTO doesn't include a timestamp in the .Log or .Event objects. If there's a better way to get the timestamp I'm all ears :) The async method I'm referring to looks like:

```
var logsProcessor = web3.Processing.Logs.CreateProcessorForContract<TransferEventDTO>(ContractAddress, (Func<EventLog<TransferEventDTO>, Task>)(async sl =>
{
   HexBigInteger blockNumber = new HexBigInteger(sl.Log.BlockNumber);
   blockFromChain = await web3.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(blockNumber);
   code goes here...
}
```

The application is a .Net 7 C# console app.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

the same thing happened to me.

To check if it is a problem with the Nethereum library, I need to create a service that simulates the Web3 library, and I got the same result.
If you use public endpoints from providers like(DRPC, 1RPC, etc.) from time to time you can get responses that have a null value for the result field( {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":null}).

I use .Net Polly library to achieve retry and wait functionality and in most cases, after 1 or 2 retries I get good value for the result field in provider responses.